# Cloudformation access control based on template_url

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm currently enrolled in one of my courses which use AWS EMR. Everytime I want to use EMR, I have to launch a .sh (let's call it `launch.sh`) script which is basically launching a cloudformation template (let's say it's called `cf.json`). There's a `template_url` variable in `launch.sh` which direct it to a json file in s3 (`cf.json`) with http endpoint.

I have permission to write & read to that bucket (not delete / attach acl). And I successfully created a copy of `cf.json` and I call it `cf2.json`. However, when I point `launch.sh` to `cf2.json`, I get permission denied error.

Do you know what causes this? Is there any permission control regarding `template_url` in cloudformation?

here's the error which I get. I masked all the details in the log to prevent privacy issues.

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateStack operation: User:
 arn:aws:sts::12345678:assumed-role/CrossStack-IamRole-
ABCDEFGH/i-0123456 is not authorized to perform:
 cloudformation:CreateStack on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-
1:12345678:stack/student-emr/*
```

However when I use the original url I got a success message:

```
Creating EMR Cluster. This will take about 15 minutes...
{
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:12345678:stack/student-emr/some-hash-id"
}
```

this is the script in `launch.sh`

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --region $emr_region --stack-name $stackname \
    --template-url $template_url \
    --parameters ParameterKey=Owner,ParameterValue=$student_id \
    --role-arn $cf_role_arn
```

I changed the value of `$template_url` variable

**NOTE**

Both .json files (`cf.json` & `cf2.json`) does not have `public-read` ACL and I've confirmed it by trying to copy the file from my personal computer which returns 403 when trying to perform `s3 cp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in AWS Documentation here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-cloudformation-security-best-practices/

You can enforce template_url in the IAM role

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "cloudformation:CreateStack",
            “cloudformation:UpdateStack”
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "cloudformation:TemplateURL": [
                    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/IAM_Users_Groups_and_Policies.template"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "cloudformation:CreateStack",
            "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "cloudformation:TemplateURL": "true"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```